# Is either of 'at the same time as you create ...' / 'at the same time that you create ...' unacceptable?

Tags: grammaticality, word-usage

The following sentence doesn't sound right to me, but I'm not sure whether it's actually wrong:

> If neither approval nor a purchase order is required, you can quickly
>   create invoices **at the same time AS** you create records for the
>   vendors.

It seems to me it should say:

> ...you can quickly create invoices **at the same time THAT** you create
>   records for the vendors.

Comment: Agreed.. the "as" seems redundant.

Comment: _That, as,_ and `Zero` may all occur.

Comment: *As* is the most common marker for comparatives of equality: *same..as*, *such..as*. See *CGEL*, p.1100.

Comment: BTW, non-lawyers should not be playing at writing boilerplate clauses that work. That's a secret language, not English, and only lawyers have the superpower of creating new spells in it.

Answer (score 4):

They're both fine.  Both the Ngram Viewer and a general web search show that both uses are popular, with "same time as" having a slight edge.  The "as" construct requires some interpolation:  "at the same time as [the time]," but that's no hill for a climber.

Answer (score 1):

In the OP, two predicates, *create invoices* and *create records*, are connected in time by the phrase *[at the same time](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/at-the-same-time)*:

> 1 Simultaneously; at once.
>
> *<sub>ODO</sub>*

The conjunction *[as](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/as)* supports the connection in the first example:

> 1. ... you can quickly create invoices **at the same time AS** you create records for the
>      vendors.

The conjunction *[that](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/that)* supports the connection in the second example:

> 2. ... you can quickly create invoices **at the same time THAT** you create
>      records for the vendors.

Neither conjunction is necessary for the construction to make sense, because the phrase *at the same time* functions as a conjunction:

> 3. ... you can quickly create invoices **at the same time** you create
>      records for the vendors.

Testing the claim that *at the same time* functions as a conjunction, we simply replace it with the conjunction *as* for a fourth construction with equivalent meaning:

> 4. ... you can quickly create invoices **as** you create records for the vendors.